# GET_STATE_BY_RANGE "no ledger context" returned when trying to query with pagination in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting:

```
2020-09-24 16:15:34.836 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> ERRO 260276 [Z] Failed to handle GET_STATE_BY_RANGE. error: no ledger context
```

when trying to do a getStateByRangeWithPagination() query in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 with LevelDB.

Is pagination only supported in CouchDB or I'm missing something?

Comment: LevelDB supports getStateByRange too. Did you get the error messages for every transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular query is a rich query which are only supported in CouchDB. You can read more about CouchDB-specific queries in the official documentation here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_as_state_database.html#couchdb-pagination